# Making combinations with arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

```
char *combo [] = {"node", "game", "loop", "good"};
```

How can I make a combination of 12 letter words using the array shown above. Example of combinations:

- nodegameloop
- loopgoodnode
- gamegamegame
- looploopgame

*"All combinations must be accounted for. The usage of nested loops is necessary."*

Comment: I tried a multidimensional array with 3 subscripts, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @ChristianSeverin [Homework Tag Is Deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @WhozCraig: oh, thanks. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You SHOULD try something before posting.
If I understood you right:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)  
    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
            printf("%s%s%s\n", combo[i], combo[j], combo[k]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 4^3 combination.
You can create all of these like:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   for (int k=0; k<4; k++)
   {
      for (int y=0; y<4; y++)
      {
            cout << combo[i] << combo[k] << combo[y] << endl;
      }     
   }
}
```